# How to do logging in fs2 Stream.takeWhile

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2

We have a Stream of events that are being pulled from kafka using fs2-kafka and we are finishing processing when the events are newer than a given deadline or the offset is at the end of the partition (this does not matter too much for the question, but to give a bit of context about the program).

We ideally would want to log when those conditions are met, but `takeWhile` and `takeThrough` require pure functions `O => Boolean`.

Our stream is:

```
partitionStream
  .takeWhile(shouldProcess(processingDelay, _))
  .takeThrough(!atLogEndOffset(_, endOffsets))
```

Obviously we could do a `log.info` inside `shouldProcess` and `atLongEndOffset` but that would mean side effecting inside a pure function, something we would prefer not doing.

What approach would be better without calling the functions twice (one for logging and one for the condition evaluation)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the element that failed the predicate for the log? or you just want a simple `"END REACHED"` like log?

Comment: Logging is the never ending debate in regards to pure vs non-pure. Personal opinion: save yourself the trouble of jumping hoops and just log where needed.

Comment: at what condition do you want to log exactly?

Comment: I want to log, reached the condition with this data (coming from the event). Will do some impure logging at the moment and refactor if we find a better solution